# Add Controls to HTML5 Time Field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Assuming the use of an HTML 5 input type=time form field

```html
<input type="time">
```

input field, is it possible to add any controls (up/down arrows, scrollers, whatever) to the field, so that the controls can be used to select the time values?

JavaScript of jQuery controls are preferred, if native HTML5 controls are not available. CSS controls (webkit?) are OK assuming good cross-browser (current browsers) compatibility.

Comment: arrow controls come by default in input type time.

Comment: @rootShiv Not in Safari, and not in Chrome, and not in Firefox. Where are you observing that?

Comment: it's working in  chrome and firefox cant say about safari.

Comment: @rootShiv When you talk about "arrow controls", do you refer to Arrow key handlers, or graphical, clickable elements the user gets presented?

Comment: I am aware that arrow controls (up/down arrow, for example) doesn't appear in all browsers. (They don't appear in my up-to-date Firefox.) So looking for a solution that will ensure that the controls appear in all (current) browsers.